# Making route event layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing, dynamic-segmentation

In my situation:
I have a CSV file with information about specific road segments: Road number, start kilometer, end kilometer.

And I have road shapefile with Road numbers.

The task is to create a layer only with road segments. I used ArcGIS Desktop but now I need to solve this task with QGIS.

Is there any alternative in QGIS for ArcMap tool "Make route event layer"?

The tool creates a temporary feature layer using routes and route events.

Comment: you need to explain what that tool does

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [LRS plugin](http://blazek.github.io/lrs/) (LRS stand for linear referencing system, sometime called dynamic segmentation)

Extract from the [plugin documentation](http://blazek.github.io/lrs/release/help.1.2.0/index.html) :

> **Features**
>
> - Standard LRS tasks: calibration (creation of LRS), creation of    punctual and linear events and calculation of measures for points.
> - Support for all vector formats supported by QGIS.
> - Supported are lines, multi-lines, points, multi-points. The lines    don’t need to be oriented. Single route may be represented by
>   multiple features.
> - Dynamic list and layer of errors and layer of quality which are    updated immediately when source layer features is edited.
> - The generated LRS is stored in memory only.
> - Interpolation between points by default, optional extrapolation.